# How to load nested classes in Java?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I have the following java code:

```
public class CheckInnerStatic {

private static class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static block initialized");
    }
    public Test () {
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }
}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("Inside main");
        Class.forName("Test");    // Doesn't work, gives ClassNotFoundException
        //Test test = new Test();   // Works fine
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the `class.forName("Test")` work here while the next line works fine?

Comment: Just to set the terminologies right, there's nothing like a static inner class. You've nested classes - static and non-static (inner).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `Outer$Nested` (regardless if nested class is static or not)

```
public class CheckInnerStatic {

    private static class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static block initialized");
    }
    public Test () {
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }
}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("Inside main");
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("CheckInnerStatic$Test");
        //Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the fully qualified class name, i.e. `yourpackage.CheckInnerStatic$Test` (assuming you defined a package, otherwise skip that part).

Comment: Sorry to say but that doesn't seem to work either, am i wrong? Also how am I able to instantiate the Test class without giving the full name as you said but am not able to load it?

Comment: Use `yourpackage.CheckInnerStatic$Test`. The $ sign is used to qualify inner classes.

Comment: please update your answer. You need to use $ character instead of dot to load inner class.

Answer (score 7):

```
Class innerClass = Class.forName("com.foo.OuterClass$InnerClass");
```